# How to make student id card in horizontal shape

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

How to make student id card in horizontal shape?

This code showing id card in vertical shape and I want in horizontal shape. How can I fix this issue? Please help me to fix this issue.

I want it like this:

```
----------------------------------
| Photo    | Student Detail      |
----------------------------------
  here     |Student Name :       |
           |Roll No:             |
  photo    |Classs :             |
           |Grn    :             |
           |Father Name :        |
----------------------------------
```

and now its showing like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
Photo                  |        Student Detail         |
--------------------------------------------------------
      here     |                     
               |
      photo    |
               |
               |
--------------------------------------------------------
Student Name:                                          |
Roll No:                                               |
Class:                                                 |
Grn:                                                   |
Father Name:                                           |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Code:

```
echo "<table class='hovertable' border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
echo "<tr><th>Photo</th><th>Student Detail</th></tr>";

if ($rows > 0) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr><td>";
      echo "<img src=http://localhost/student/images/".$row['photo'] ." width='150' height='100'></a></td>";
      echo "<tr><tr><td>";
                echo $row['name'];
                echo "</tr></td>";
        echo "<tr><td>";
                echo $row['rollno'];
                echo "</tr></td>";
        echo "<td>";
                echo $row['fathername'];
                echo "</tr></td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row['class'];
                echo "</td></tr>";

        }
} else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan=\"5\">No results found!</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Why you are echoing out so much HTML using PHP?

Comment: i would rater use `div` with some good `css` then use a `table` anyway try to place some width around

Comment: fabio how can i fix it can you tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details are below the photo, because you start a new row before `$row['name']`. You cannot nest rows the way you do. If you want to have the details side by side with the photo, you must start with a `<td>` tag and then break the parts with either `<br/>`

```
echo '<td>';
echo $row['name'], '<br/>';
echo $row['rollno'], '<br/>';
echo $row['fathername'], '<br/>';
echo $row['class'], '<br/>';
echo '</td></tr>';
```

or `<div>` tags, as @Fabio already suggested in the comments.